# Nuxt html style injection

Tags: css, nuxt.js

Is there a way to add style to html only for a specific page, without using different layout.(and also even if i try and use layout nuxt loads all styles and is no good anyway)
I just need to add overflow:hidden to html for my index page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go with bodyAttrs in your page component

```
<script>
export default {
  head: {
    bodyAttrs: {
      class: 'overflow-hidden'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  in style tag like this link:

```
<template>
  <-- index page --->
</template>    

<style>
html {
   overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

if you do not use scoped in style it can effect on html tag

```
<style>
/* global styles */
</style>

<style scoped>
/* local styles */
</style>
```

Comment: if global it does effect all pages. if scoped it doesn't have any effect on html or body